# D3.js ~ Drop down lists with dependency based on dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a set of drop down lists in order to populate a graph only with the data the user wants. I managed to get it work with one drop down list, which accesses the nested data I set up from the original csv. What I'd like to do now, is to access the selected value in the first drop down and show the variables but I'm not really sure how to get the selected value using js or d3.js (I'd gladly avoid using other stuff, if possible). What I have so far is:

**EDIT: changed the code a bit, like so:**

```
d3.select("#elenco")
    .append("select")
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", "---")
    .text("---");
d3.select("#elenco")
    .select("select")
    .on("change", function (d) {
        var questo = this.value;
        sel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        circle.filter(function () { return this.id == questo; }).attr("r", 5);
        circle.filter(function () { return this.id != questo; }).attr("r", 1); 
        if (this.value == "---") { return circle.attr("r", 2); };

        d3.select("#elenco2")
            .select("select")
            .on("change", function (d) { null })
            .selectAll("option")
            .data(nested.filter(function () { return nested.key == sel })) 
            .enter()
            .append("option")
            .attr("value", function (d){ return d.StyleName; })
            .text(function (d){ return d.StyleName; })
    })
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(nested)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function (d){ return d.key; })
    .text(function (d){ return d.key; });

d3.select("#elenco2")
    .append("select")
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", "---")
    .text("---");
```

Now I can access the selected value by setting up a global variable `sel` (thanks Lars!) but I have trouble accessing the right value of data I need, right now the `nested` dataset is structured like so: 
[image]

Every `Objec`t (the `d.FamilyName`) has a series of objects (sorted by the `d.Stylename`) with other data. I got access to one of those in the console through:

```
console.log(nested[0].values[0].StyleName)
```

Which returns the first value of the first array, but I'd like to get in the second dropdown each StyleName contained in the selected array, like for example in the `first dropdown` if I select the `Times` font, in the `second` it returns the `Bold, Regular, Light weights`, but I don't know how to call that.
Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a day working on it I made it work like this:

```
  d3.select("#elenco")
    .append("select")
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", "---")
    .text("---");
  d3.select("#elenco")
    .select("select")
    .on("change", function (d) {
        var questo = this.value;
        var questoindex = this.selectedIndex;
        var circlefilter = circle.filter(function () { return this.id == questo; }).attr("r", 5);
        circle.filter(function () { return this.id != questo; }).attr("r", 1); 
        if (this.value == "---") { return circle.attr("r", 2); };
        d3.select("#elenco2").select("select").selectAll("option").remove(); //this removes the previous options from previous selections in the first drop down

        d3.select("#elenco2")
            .select("select")
            .append("option")
            .attr("value", "---")
            .text("---");
        d3.select("#elenco2")
            .select("select")
            .selectAll("option")
            .data(nested[questoindex].values)
            .enter()
            .append("option")
            .attr("value", function (d){ return d.StyleName; })
            .text(function (d){ return d.StyleName; });
        d3.select("#elenco2")
            .select("select")
            .on("change", function (d) {
                var quello = this.value;
                circlefilter.filter(function (d) { return d.StyleName == quello; }).attr("r", 5);
                circlefilter.filter(function (d) { return d.StyleName != quello; }).attr("r", 3); 
                if (this.value == "---") { return circlefilter.attr("r", 5); }
            });
        })
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(nested)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function (d){ return d.key; })
    .text(function (d){ return d.key; });

d3.select("#elenco2")
    .append("select")
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", "---")
    .text("---");
```

I have to be honest that this involved a lot of trying and luck to make everything work, but now the dependent drop down works and most of all is done only with d3 and a bit of basic javascript. Maybe this could have been done in an easier and more compact way, but like this it's working and somewhat easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

- Run all the code that relies on the selected value inside the `change` handler.
- Declare a global variable that you set inside the `change` handler. You would still need to call a function that makes the changes, as only the handler knows when a change occurs.

To then select the values for the second dropdown based on the value in the first, you would need code somewhat like this.

```
var choices;
for(key in nested) {
  if(key == sel) {
    choices = nested[key].values.map(function(d) { return d.StyleName; });
  }
}
// do something interesting with choices
```

Comment: My problem is, if for example, I set the selected id in a variable, like var selected = this.id, how can I access it in the other dropdown menu? i guess that the dataset would be something filtered based on that value, but my problem is how can I access that outside of the on change function?

Comment: Make it a global variable (i.e. declare it outside the handler) and set it inside the handler.

Comment: but also the creation of the second drop down items should be put on the first on change correct?

Comment: If the values in the second depend on the selection in the first, yes.

Comment: looks like I need some more help then, I'll add some more information on the question in a sec.

Comment: I'm sorry to comment again but I really don't understand how to implement your answer, the selected value that I need to take to the other dropdown is already stored in the var 'questo', so in the .data relative to the second dropdown i tried to put:
.data(nested.filter(function (d) { return d.key == questo; })) 
but did not work

Comment: Could you post a complete working example somewhere? That would make it easier to understand where exactly that would need to go.

Comment: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/grado_squadratura_dropdown.html
here's what i have so far, sorry but some stuff is in italian. PRIMO DD is the first dropdown, SECONDO DD is the second one. hope this clarifies what I am trying to do. I also managed to get the index of the value and to refer to it, using "questoindex" but again I am not able to access the StyleName data contained in each array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you would need to put the code here: `d3.select("#elenco2").select("select").selectAll("option").data(choices).enter().append("option") // etc`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! You can use `this.selectedIndex` to get the the index of, well, the currently selected index:

```
d3.json('movies.json', function(movieArray){
  d3.select("#selectNumber")
      .on("change", function(){
        updateMovie(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);})
    .selectAll("option").data(movieArray).enter().append("option")
      .text(function(d){ return d.replace(/_/g, " ") })
      .attr("value", function(d){ return d });
});
```

https://github.com/1wheel/film-strips/blob/master/wrapper.js

Comment: hey first of all thanks for the answer and the cheering! :) but looks like my problem is kind of different from what I stated in the first answer, I've edited it a bit